# How do I prepopulate the value of Select List in Bootstrap?

Tags: sql, twitter-bootstrap, selectlist

I am using bootstrap framework to create a simple form that will be used to edit a SQL db record.  To be concise, I have only posted a small snippet of code, a Select List input only.  How do I automatically set a specific value from the list?  I expected that I could use

```
<select class="form-control" id=".....  value="Option1">
```

but that did not work.  My ultimate outcome is to set the value using a SQL query.

```html
<!--- Location Drop Down--->
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="post_record.php">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputLocation" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Location</label>
   <div class="col-sm-4">
    <select class="form-control" id="inputLocation" name="inputLocation" value="Option1">
     <option value="0">Please Select</option>
                    <option value="1">Option1</option>
                                     
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "*********";
$password = "*********";
$dbname = "**********";

// Create Connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

//Check connection
if (!$conn) {
trigger_error("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
  }
if ($conn) {
echo "success";
}

$stmt = "SELECT DISTINCT `ACT_LOCATION` FROM `actual_data`";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$stmt) or die(mysqli_error());
while(list($category) = mysqli_fetch_row($result)){
echo '<option value="'.$category.'">'.$category.'</option>';
      }
?>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add attribute `selected="selected"` for the `<option>` that you want to be default selected option :

```
<option value="1" selected="selected">Option1</option>
```